# Not able retrieve floor data using Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension in NWC file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am trying to find the mix and max of floors in autodesk forge viewer.
For getting levels I used 'Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension' extension in autodesk.
by using this extension I retrieve the floor data and then calculate the min and max
the above approach works well with .rvt files but does not work for .nwc

the reason some people told is while exporting to .nwc AEC data is not included.

so my question is, is there any other way I can retrieve the floor data of floor max and mix in autodesk forge viewer

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the properties of a Revit floor in an RVT BIM imported into a NavisWorks NWD file.

Among many others, the floor contains the following Revit `Element` properties:

```
Element (LcRevitData_Element)
  Name (LcRevitPropertyElementName) = Generic 150mm (DisplayString)
  Type (LcRevitPropertyElementType) = Generic 150mm (DisplayString)
  Family (LcRevitPropertyElementFamily) = Floor (DisplayString)
  Category (LcRevitPropertyElementCategory) = Floors (DisplayString)
  Id (LcRevitPropertyElementId) = 346574 (Int32)
  Level (lcldrevit_parameter_-1001952) = LcRevitElement(Level "Level 1", #311) (NamedConstant)
  Height Offset From Level (lcldrevit_parameter_-1001951) = 0 (DoubleLength)
  Structural (lcldrevit_parameter_-1001954) = false (Boolean)
  Phase Created (lcldrevit_parameter_-1012100) = LcRevitElement(Phase "New Construction", #86961) (NamedConstant)
  Enable Analytical Model (lcldrevit_parameter_-1001552) = false (Boolean)
  Slope (lcldrevit_parameter_-1006016) = 0.00° (DisplayString)
  Room Bounding (lcldrevit_parameter_-1001007) = true (Boolean)
  Perimeter (lcldrevit_parameter_-1001953) = 74.8 (DoubleLength)
  Area (lcldrevit_parameter_-1012805) = 325.5 (DoubleArea)
  Volume (lcldrevit_parameter_-1012806) = 160.19 (DoubleVolume)
  Related to Mass (lcldrevit_parameter_-1001713) = false (Boolean)
  Elevation at Top (lcldrevit_parameter_-1001598) = 0 (DoubleLength)
  Elevation at Bottom (lcldrevit_parameter_-1001561) = -0.49 (DoubleLength)
  Thickness (lcldrevit_parameter_-1001900) = 0.49 (DoubleLength)
```

Afaict, the elevation at top and bottom data should enable you to retrieve the information you are after.

Of course, this will only work assuming the following is true:

- The floors are authored in Revit
- The Revit `Element` properties I see in NavisWorks are exported to Forge

Please check and confirm whether these assumptions hold and whether that solves your problem.

In any case, we would be very interested to hear any other results and solutions that you find.

Comment: thankyou for considering this issue, but I am little bit confused where do I need to check this data ? which u posted above. do I need to check in revit software or inside viewer ?

Comment: In the viewer, using the JavaScript debugger. Maybe also in NavisWorks. We know that they are present in Revit. First, however, answer the first question: are the floors authored in Revit?